# hide li tab tag based on condition

Tags: apex, visualforce

In below code I want to hide or show second tab based on role. rendered attribute not working for li tag. is it possible with slds to show and hide based on condition?

```html
<div class="slds-tabs_scoped slds-tabs_large">
  <ul class="slds-tabs_scoped__nav" role="tablist">
    <li
      class="slds-tabs_scoped__item slds-is-active"
      title="Item One"
      role="presentation"
    >
      <a
        class="slds-tabs_scoped__link"
        href="#"
        role="tab"
        tabindex="0"
        aria-selected="true"
        aria-controls="tab-scoped-1"
        id="tab-scoped-1__item"
      >
        Item One
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="slds-tabs_scoped__item" title="Item Two" role="presentation">
      <a
        class="slds-tabs_scoped__link"
        href="#"
        role="tab"
        tabindex="-1"
        aria-selected="false"
        aria-controls="tab-scoped-2"
        id="tab-scoped-2__item"
      >
        Item Two
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="slds-tabs_scoped__item" title="Item Three" role="presentation">
      <a
        class="slds-tabs_scoped__link"
        href="#"
        role="tab"
        tabindex="-1"
        aria-selected="false"
        aria-controls="tab-scoped-3"
        id="tab-scoped-3__item"
      >
        Item Three
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div
    id="tab-scoped-1"
    class="slds-tabs_scoped__content slds-show"
    role="tabpanel"
    aria-labelledby="tab-scoped-1__item"
  >
    Item One Content
  </div>
  <div
    id="tab-scoped-2"
    class="slds-tabs_scoped__content slds-hide"
    role="tabpanel"
    aria-labelledby="tab-scoped-2__item"
  >
    Item Two Content
  </div>
  <div
    id="tab-scoped-3"
    class="slds-tabs_scoped__content slds-hide"
    role="tabpanel"
    aria-labelledby="tab-scoped-3__item"
  >
    Item Three Content
  </div>
</div>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Rendered attribute only works with native visualforce components, you can use JavaScript or CSS to hide the appropriate element.

With visualforce, a better way would be to use [`apex:outputPanel`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputPanel.htm) with `layout` set as `none`. Setting layout set as none, HTML code will not be generated for outputPanel visualforce tag and thus not distort your UI.

```html
<apex:outputPanel rendered={!yourCondition} layout="none">
  <li class="slds-tabs_scoped__item" title="Item Two" role="presentation">
    <a
      class="slds-tabs_scoped__link"
      href="#"
      role="tab"
      tabindex="-1"
      aria-selected="false"
      aria-controls="tab-scoped-2"
      id="tab-scoped-2__item"
    >
      Item Two
    </a>
  </li>
</apex:outputPanel>
```